# Pass nested class to constructor using reflection

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to pass a nested class to another `ViewModel` who has constructor like this:

```
 public CityEditViewModel(CityListViewModel.CityInfo info)
        {
            Model = Library.CityEdit.GetItem(info.Model.CityID);
        }
```

The class from where I'm getting data is `CityListViewModel` and in it is a nested class `CityInfo`.

In details.
I have a `datagrid` whose items are of type `CityInfo`. Well, when I select that item from `datagrid`, it should open new `ViewModel` who is `CitiyEditViewModel` (It should send that class to my constructor above).

I have tried following:

```
Type EditClass = GetMyClass(subClass); //getting my CityEditViewModel
ConstructorInfo editConstructor = EditClass.GetConstructor(new Type[] { ChildClass }); // getting the constructor of that class
IScreen screen = (IScreen)(Activator.CreateInstance(EditClass, editConstructor )); //this part activates the window


    //GetMyClass method
    public Type GetMyClass(string type)
    {
        return Type.GetType(type);
    }
```

But I get method does not exist exception.

Comment: What does `EditClass.GetConstructors()` return?

Comment: What is `ChildClass`? How does it rely to `CityListViewModel.CityInfo`?

Comment: Where are you passing the constructor parameter?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen It returns all constructors in class `CityEditViewModel`.
`ChildClass` is `CityInfo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line, you're trying to call the constructor `CityEditViewModel(CityEditViewModel.CityInfo)`:

```
IScreen screen = (IScreen)(Activator.CreateInstance(EditClass, 
    editConstructor ));
```

[That overload of `CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) takes one or more parameters. The first is the `Type` of the class to construct. The second and subsequent parameters are the parameters that it you want it to pass along to the constructor. It uses reflection to find a constructor matching that set of parameters in that order. If it finds one, it calls it to create an instance of the type.

You're passing a constructor parameter of type `ConstructorInfo`. `CityEditViewModel` doesn't have a constructor that takes a parameter of that type. That method does not exist. Hence the exception. I'm getting `System.MissingMethodException` with a message of `"Constructor on type 'CityEditViewModel' not found."`. The message would be better if it indicated that *some particular* constructor was not found, but I've seen worse.

Pass it `CityEditViewModel.CityInfo` instead:

```
var cityInfo = whateverThingUserClickedOn as CityEditViewModel.CityInfo;

IScreen screen = (IScreen)(Activator.CreateInstance(EditClass, 
    cityInfo ));
```

But that cast is for your benefit, not `Activator.CreateInstance()`. The constructor parameters are `object`, so it doesn't need the cast:

```
IScreen screen = (IScreen)(Activator.CreateInstance(EditClass, 
    whateverThingUserClickedOn ));
```

And delete this next line; you don't need it. `Activator.CreateInstance()` finds the constructor for you based on the types of the parameters you give it.

```
ConstructorInfo editConstructor = EditClass.GetConstructor(
    new Type[] { ChildClass }); // getting the constructor of that class
```

Comment: I was sending the `Type` and the object, but with a small mistake.
I was checking my `SelectedItem` in debugger, and it was showing that it comes from class type `CityListViewModel + CityInfo`. I tought the `+` would reproduce a error, so I changed it to dot (.)...
Now after NOT modifying the `SelectedItem` it works perfectly.

Comment: Not modifying SelectedItem? Not sure what you mean, but if it works it works.